# I want to create a div or more inside the section when I press the submit button

Tags: javascript

I have stopped refreshing the page by using e.preventDefault but the code is not executing as I want.
Here is the most important part

Here is the complete code

```html
<div class="page">
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" id="input-field" />


        <input type="submit" value="Add Task" />
    </form>
    <section class="tasks" id="tasks"></section>


</div>
```

```js
//here variables
let submitt =document.querySelector("input[type='submit']")
let val =document.getElementById("input-field");
let clickk =document.getElementById("cli");
let divv = document.createElement("div");
divv.title = val.value;
divv.id = "iddd";
divv.className ="classone";
//append the text in the div
divv.append(val.value)
divv.style.cssText = "width:100px;height:50px;background:red;color:white;"

let sec = document.getElementById("tasks")
//func to create new div 
submitt.addEventListener("submit",function(e){

  sec.append(divv)
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: There is no ERRORS

Comment: Listen for the submit event on the form, not the input.

Answer (score 1):

hi，sounds like the submit button does not trigger the submit event as only the form can listen submit event
you should listen submit on form, or use click

```
submitt.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  sec.append(divv)
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Oooh, you are correct, but there is still a problem that  why not create more than one div when pressing again

Comment: i added the text in the div but i want to create more than one div when pressing again

Comment: hi, then you should remove the id attr of the div and put the code about create div element to the click event